# rmv using 1.9.1 when default 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I just deploy my app and after a little fight everything is running. But when I login to the console the prompt is a version it is not used by the app. I'm using rvm.

when I run rvm list I get:

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

But when I log in console with rails c production I get:

```
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.7)
1.9.1 :001 >
```

I'm using capistrano to deploy. It can be fixed if I run rvm use 1.9.3, but everytime I reboot the server same issue came along.

Does anyone faced this before?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
My .ruby-version file

```
ruby-1.9.3-p448
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be nice if you can create a .rvmrc file in your application and provide the gem set link there.
as example
like to create the file type 
echo "rvm ruby-1.8.7-p352@gemset" > .rvmrc

Inside the file type
rvm use 1.9.3
rvm gemset use rails3.2

Comment: I have done it with .ruby-version 'cause I read somewhere .rvmrc is deprecated. Shall I came back and delete .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset and create an .rvmrc again?

Comment: .rvmrc is getting depracated in new rvm versions now. Use .ruby-version instead

Comment: Are you using Ruby version in Gemfile?

Comment: Yes @techvineet its true..Please check your rvm version and do the necessary. concept is same

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh Yes, this was the first thing I did as I comment before, but the funniest thing is that ruby 1.9.1 is NOT installed on the server...

Comment: @marc in that case not sure about the problem